# how to display PDF links on other sites using OnSubmit Googleform and Iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, google-forms, onsubmit

I'm having trouble creating a link that displays a PDF file from googledrive on an HTML page such as sites.google.com or etc by OnSubmit "George1234" in GoogleForm and then displaying a PDF file named George1234.PDF stored on google drive? while the existing script examples only display templates from Googlesheet

this is the sample script that make PDF from Googlesheet

```
<iframe id="gform" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/NEWFORMID/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="427" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading..</iframe>
```

HTML

```
<iframe 
User File 
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
var load = 0;
document.getElementById('gform').onload = function() {
load++;
if(load > 1) {
document.location = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ ID_SPREADSHEET /export?Format=pdf&format=pdf&size=8&gid= GID_PRINTED &gridlines=false";
}
}
</script>
```

so how to replace document location = to files PDF stored in GoogleDrive?? and base OnSubmit Name George1234

Comment: Please show your code handling the file upload

Comment: the file is form mailmerge.. Gform+GSheet+MailmergeScript= PDF file

Comment: [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YRy5fCkC6cN7xSBLdrtVNYYjIqC2w1I3qBmsCQcuINw/edit?usp=sharing  from the file column A will Call onSubmit by GoogleForm and JavaScript Will Display Link On Column B at another SITE

Comment: Please add the code of `mailmerge` to your question.

Comment: i use autocrat to make pdf file in [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YRy5fCkC6cN7xSBLdrtVNYYjIqC2w1I3qBmsCQcuINw/edit?usp=sharing and i want to call the PDF file by using Googleform on another site like sites.google.com i found that script above but its make a PDF file by googlesheet template the original link script found here [link]https://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Fi798GFQI0

Answer (score 0):

```js
const id = file.getId();
const html= `<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/${id}/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>`;
```

Reference:

[getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getid)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... i am newby in the code,.. please give me a full code to put in my HTML iframe

Comment: No, as I told you. You should provide the code you are using. SO is not writing code for you.